# Which one of the locator is efficient by.css or by.xpath or by.id in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

Which one is better, in terms of performance , to use : by.css or by.xpath or by.id.
I have a really lengthy xpath :

```
by.xpath('//*@id="logindiv"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/nav/div/div[1]/form/div/div/button')
```

which can be used with other selectors like by.css or by.id.
But it is not very clear which one is better.

Comment: If it is not very clear which one is better, then they are about the same.  Use the one that is easiest for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protractor uses selenium-webdriver underneath for element lookup/interaction etc, so this is not protractor specific question, but rather selenium-webdriver specific.

CSS selectors perform far better than Xpath and it is well documented in Selenium community. Here are some reasons,

Xpath engines are different in each browser, hence make them inconsistent.
Last time I checked, IE does not have a native xpath engine, therefore selenium-webdriver injects its own xpath engine for compatibility of its API. Hence we lose the advantage of using native browser features that selenium-webdriver inherently promotes.
Xpath tend to become complex like your example and hence make hard to read/maintain in my opinion.

However there are some situations where, you need to use xpath, for example, searching for a parent element or searching element by its text (I wouldn't recommend the later).

You can read blog from Simon(creator of selenium-webdriver) [here](http://old.eurostarconferences.com/blog/2013/1/28/liveblogged!-automated-web-testing-traps-for-the-unwary-with-simon-stewart) . He also recommends CSS over Xpath.

So I would recommend you use id, name etc for faster lookup. If thats not available use css and finally use xpath if none other suite your situation.